# Use faceted search to drill down in hierarchical structure and omit node data outside current selection

Tags: solr, faceted-search

I have the following structure for my products, where a product may fall into multiple categories. In my case, a "caketopper", which would be under "cake/caketoppers" as well as "caketoppers" (don't focus on the logic behind the category structure in this example).

Category structure:

```
cake
    caketoppers
        funny

caketoppers
    funny
```

What I want is that when the user has chosen a category on level 0 (the main category selection), in this case 'caketoppers', I don't want to return the attributes/values that same product has because it's also in a different category.
I tried the following queries, but it keeps returning all data:

```
&f.slug_nl_0.facet.pre‌​fix=(caketoppers)&fq=slug_nl_0:"(caketoppers)"
&f.slug_nl_0.facet.pre‌​fix="caketoppers"&fq=slug_nl_0:"(caketoppers)"
```

I keep getting this result (cleaned for better readability):

```
<result name="response" numFound="6" start="0">
    <doc>
        <arr name="slug_nl_0">
            <str>caketoppers</str>
            <str>cake</str>
        </arr>
    </doc>
</result>
<lst name="facet_counts">
    <lst name="facet_fields">
        <lst name="slug_nl_0">
            <int name="cake">6</int>
            <int name="caketoppers">6</int>
        </lst>
    </lst>  
</lst>
```

But my desired result would be:

```
<result name="response" numFound="6" start="0">
    <doc>
        <arr name="slug_nl_0">
            <str>caketoppers</str>
        </arr>
    </doc>
</result>
<lst name="facet_counts">
    <lst name="facet_fields">
        <lst name="slug_nl_0">
            <int name="caketoppers">6</int>
        </lst>
    </lst>  
</lst>
```

field definition of 'slug_nl_0' in schema.xml:

**UPDATE 1**

I tried with a more simple query but I'm getting the exact same results:

```
&facet.pre‌​fix=caketoppers&fq=slug_nl_0:caketoppers
```

**UPDATE 2**

I was reading on grouping: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing

So I tried adding that in my queries, but I get errors:

`&fq=slug_nl_0:taarttoppers&group=true&group.facet=true&group.field=slug_nl_0`

error: can not use FieldCache on multivalued field: slug_nl_0

`&fq=slug_nl_0:taarttoppers&group=true&group.field=slug_nl_0`

error: can not use FieldCache on multivalued field: slug_nl_0

`&fq=slug_nl_0:taarttoppers&group.facet=true&group.field=slug_nl_0`

error: Specify the group.field as parameter or local parameter

And then I noticed this at the bottom of the page:

> Known Limitations Support for grouping on a multi-valued field has not
>   yet been implemented.

On that same [Solr FieldCollapsing example page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) they refer to Best Buy as an example. Now I wonder how that was implemented without support for multivalued fields.

**UPDATE 3**

I'm now trying another option, the PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory, this was suggested by someone else to support hierarchical navigation. I was reading here: https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/path/PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory.html

And ended up with this:

```
    <fieldType name="descendent_path" class="solr.TextField">
       <analyzer type="index">
             <tokenizer class="solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory" delimiter=">" /> 
       </analyzer>
       <analyzer type="query">
             <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
       </analyzer>
     </fieldType>
```

I tried with these field definitions:

```
    <field name="categorystring_nl" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="categorystring_tokenized" type="descendent_path" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

And these querystring parameters in the request (I also have some more categories now):

1. &facet.field=categorystring_nl --> this returns a facet with count based on full categorystring, e.g. "cake>caketoppers>funny", so I can't use that for the count on the highest category level (in this case "cake"):

> ```
> <lst name="categorystring_nl">
>   <int name="party>balloons">15</int>
>   <int name="cake>caketoppers>funny">6</int>
>   <int name="caketoppers>funny">6</int>
>   <int name="accessories>tiaras">3</int>
> </lst>
> ```

2. &facet.field=categorystring_tokenized, this now returns:

> ```
> <lst name="categorystring_tokenized">
>   <int name="party">15</int>
>   <int name="party>balloons">15</int>
>   <int name="cake">6</int>
>   <int name="cake>caketoppers">6</int>
>   <int name="cake>caketoppers>funny">6</int>
>   <int name="caketoppers">6</int>
>   <int name="caketoppers>funny">6</int>
>   <int name="accessories">3</int>
>   <int name="accessories>tiaras">3</int>
> </lst>
> ```

I think this is the data one would expect from tokenizing? But right now I still don't see how I can easily extract the hierarchy from this data, except by looping through the facets and count the number of ">" occurrences in the "name" attribute to determine the actual level in the hierarchy and build the hierarchy in the facets. There must be a better way?

What can I do?

Comment: A facet search won't change the content of your document in any way, so you'll still get the same document regardless of what your facet query is (in the `doc/arr` element). The facets should be reduced by the prefix, but try without () and "" around the term, and use the general `facet.prefix` without a field prefix while debugging and trying to get stuff to work.

Comment: I updated my question, I tried your suggestion, but no luck...what else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

The search mapping should be designed to be found. Not to reflect the original data.

It sounds to me that may actually want to index nearly the same content as multiple entries, one for each category. Solr is pretty efficient about representing repeated indexed data (stored is a different issue), so you should not need to worry about the performance of that.

If you then need to re-normalize those multiple results, you could look at grouping and other other features on top of that.

Comment: Thanks, updated my question as grouping is not supported on multi valued fields. So I'm not sure what to do next.